# Регулярное выражение для получения id пользователя

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

В общем, нужно вывести из строки id пользователя до запятой. В данном коде выводит "id50,", надо только "50". Как?)

```
   text = 'id50, 4124fdgfgdfg';
      if(text.match('id[0-9].*,')){
        komy = text.match('id[0-9].*,');
        alert(komy);
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью регулярного выражения `^id(\d+),.*$` (захватывается число в скобках после id, и до запятой). Можно сразу захватить и вторую часть (`4124fdgfgdfg`), таким выражением: `/^id(\d+), (.*)$/`.

Рабочий пример:

```js
str = 'id42, 4124fdgfgdfg';
if (m = str.match(/^id(\d+), (.*)$/)) {
  console.log(m[1], m[2])
}
```

Дает в консоль (можете нажать кнопку "Выполнить код" для проверки):

> 42 4124fdgfgdfg

Здесь хорошее описание `match` на русском: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Здесь https://regex101.com/ вы можете онлайн поиграть с регулярными выражениями и сразу видеть результат. Вот ваш пример с тестами и комментариями: https://regex101.com/r/nX1rF5/2

Comment: Вот как раз при `match` или `exec` придётся пилить велосипеды, иначе `Cannot read property '1'`

Comment: @Doofy скорее всего в любом случае понадобится условие корректности входной строки, так что это даже плюс. Ну и как бонус можно захватывать сразу несколько разных подстрок разными паттернами.

Comment: Не согласен. В моём ответе одна строка и id либо найден, либо нет, без лишних проверок

Comment: Вы прям читайте мои мысли, как раз нужно было еще сделать разделение на ID и следующего текста) Спасибо)

Answer (score 6):

Вариантов куча:
Можно поправить само выражение и будет работать:

```js
// (?<=id) - смотрит позитивно назад, но не берёт в результат
// (?=,) - смотрит позитивно вперёд, но не берёт в результат
// + перед выражением пытается привести результат к Number
//
// Вернётся либо ["50"], либо null;
//    массив с одним элементом попытается привести первый элемент
//    null станет 0
// Используйте эти знания на благо Вашей проверки :)
console.info(+/(?<=id)\d*(?=,)/.exec('id50, 4124fdgfgdfg')); // 50
```

Можно, конечно, использовать старые, добрые группы (можно даже [именованные сделать](http://trentrichardson.com/2011/08/02/javascript-regexp-match-named-captures/)):

```js
// С помощью тернарного оператора проверяем на null
//    Если null - вернём 0
//    Если есть результат - приводим к Number 1 элемент (в 0 - всё совпадение, т. е. id50,)
console.info((r = /id(\d*),/.exec('id50, 4124fdgfgdfg')) ? +r[1] : 0); // 50
```

Можно извращаться типа `String.prototype.split` заюзать, где с помощью тех же групп сохраняется номер, но зачем использовать ножовку для забивки гвоздей?

Comment: для первого примера: _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=id)\\d*(?=,)/: Invalid group",_

Comment: @Grundy, потому что js не поддерживает эту штуку.

Comment: @Qwertiy, но вопрос-то про js

Comment: @Grundy, но ответ-то не мой ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, поэтому к тебе никаких претензий :-)

Comment: @Grundy, я тоже так думал (даже знал), но `Chrome v51` так не думает: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zlGGF.png

Comment: Один хром не показатель, ну и в версии _Версия 51.0.2704.106 m_ все еще падает с указанной ошибкой

Comment: У меня `51.0.2704.103 m` (староват, конечно) и работает: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kzXJe.png Может и не показатель, но раз в одном из популярнейших (если не самом) браузере работает - с этим надо считаться.

Answer (score 5):

При `match` или `exec` придётся использовать дополнительные проверки, иначе возможна ошибка *Cannot read property '1'*

`split` либо найдёт, либо нет (*undefined*)

```js
text = 'id50, 4124fdgfgdfg';
t = text.split(/id(\d+), (.*)/);
console.log(t[1], t[2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
text = ' id50, 4124fdgfgdfg';
console.log(text.replace(/id(\d+)\s*,.*|./gi, '$1'))

text = ' id50, 4124fdgfgdfg id100,';
console.log(text.replace(/id(\d+)\s*,.*|./gi, '$1'))

text = ' id, 4124fdgfgdfg';
console.log(text.replace(/id(\d+)\s*,.*|./gi, '$1'))
```

Answer (score -3):

Никак, но можно так (вместе с `id`):

```
/id\d[^,]*/
```